# Return a number which is not repeated even number of times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete the following challenge...

> Given an array of integers, find the one that appears an odd number of times.
>
> There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times.

This is my current solution, that does not work. I believe there is a logic error somewhere but I am unsure. Any alternative ways to approach the solution that are beginner friendly are welcome also.

I am fairly new to JavaScript so please go easy!

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let arrayCount = [];
    let num = A[i]
    for (let x = 0; x < A.length; x++)
        if (A[i] === num) {
        arrayCount.push(num);
        //console.log(arrayCount);
        i++;
        }
    if (arrayCount.length % 2 !== 0) {
      return num;
    }
  }
}

const checkList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

console.log(findOdd(checkList));
```

Comment: could you have three or more of the same value?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, any odd number of times, but only for a single integer.

Comment: i was asking, because of the subject and *"twice"* ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: @HaoWu This is probably a great solution! But I have no idea what this means as a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

Since they're all numbers, you can *toggle* a number using [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR):

```
0 ^ 1                 -->  1
0 ^ 1 ^ 1             -->  0
0 ^ 1 ^ 1 ^ 2         -->  2
0 ^ 1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2     -->  0
0 ^ 1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 3 -->  3
```

```js
const findOdd = arr => {
  let num = 0;
  for(let i of arr) {
    num ^= i;
  }
  return num;
};

console.log(findOdd([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]));
```

---

If you're not dealing with numbers, you can still *toggle* them using object keys:

```js
const findOdd = arr => {
  const obj = {};
  
  for(let i of arr) {
    // "toggle" the element, if i exists, add it to the object, otherwise remove it
    if(obj[i]) {
      delete obj[i];
    } else {
      obj[i] = true;
    }
  }
  
  return Object.keys(obj)[0];
};

console.log(findOdd(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd']));
```

Comment: Just headsup the XOR trick will fail for numbers over `2 ** 31 - 1` (and lower than `-(2 ** 31)` ) as the number will be more than 32 bit and bitwise operations truncate to 32 bits only.

Comment: As a separate note, the toggle logic in the second case is easier expressed as `obj[i] = !obj[i]` no need for `if`/`else`. Then you can take the only one where the value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is, you are pushing any duplicates of any number to `arrayCount`, and so, its `length` will not be the length of a single repetetive number. Here is how I would approach this:

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  const counts = {};
  A.forEach(function (number) {
    const currentCount = counts[number];
    if (!currentCount) {
      counts[number] = 1;
    } else {
      counts[number] = currentCount + 1;
    }
  });
  
  return Object.entries(counts).find(([_, count]) => count % 2 !== 0)[0];
}

const checkList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

console.log(findOdd(checkList));
```

Comment: `Object.entries(counts).forEach(function ([number, count]) { if (count % 2 !== 0) { oddCountNumber = number; });` - this is *much* shorter expressed as `Object.entries(counts).find(([, count]) => count % 2 !== 0)[0];`